# Crystal Report suppress a whole row in details section

Tags: crystal-reports, report, row, suppress

I am using crystal report in my vb.net program. Because of my database design I get some rows duplicated as in the following picture: [image]

As you can see from the picture, the first record has two printer models that have the same ink group. and the next model is the only model that has that particular ink group. As I have mentioned before This is because the way I designed the database and its not the problem. I know how to suppress a single column.

When I select a column and check "suppress if duplicate", the following results show: [image]

The row is suppressed but also has taken a place in the report details.

My question now is how to suppress a whole duplicated row?
thank you

Comment: This problem can be resolved simply by selecting Distinct option from Report Option. But, I would like to suggest you to update relationship link in crystal report Database Explorer. If you are using command then there is something wrong condition in joining.

Comment: This Database design that allows exact duplicates will land you in trouble at some point.

Answer (score 0):

As you are aware that your database design is producing these type of results, one option would be check the option *Select Distinct Records* so that only distinct records are displayed.

```
One more option.. This is not a tested one change as you required, This is just an idea
```

write a condition in supress of the section where you placed your data.

```
if ID=next(ID)
then true
else false
```

This condition will make sure that if next row is duplicated then it will be supressed

Comment: This only suppress one column but not the full row! Then I tried to apply that to all the columns and was ok but there were spaces between rows.

Comment: I cant find the select distinct option. VS2010

Comment: I am discussing abot CR as a standalone application but no idea how to do it using VS2010... I didn't get **spaces between rows** any screenshot will be useful to answer

Comment: I dont know how to paste a picture in  a comment but I can in  the question. But what I meant is that the rows get suppressed but as if it exists. Meaning the suppressed row has taken place in the report details but it is suppressed.

Comment: ok now you achieved the supress by applying the condition on individual fileds now apply the same condition on section so that the section gets supressed.

Comment: Why may I suppress the section?! Not the whole section that I need to suppress

Comment: As you said columns are supressed but you are getting empty spaces thats why I suggested you to apply condition at section level

Comment: Well, how to do that for a section? I tried right click on the section but gone no where!

Comment: Right click section, and go to section expert there for supress write the conditional formula

Comment: the problem is that I have a subreport in that section. Doing it has mixed up things together. I will try to do it in the subreport

Answer (score 0):

there is many Options , Easy one Is,
 you can use Grouping in Crystal report , in your Example u can Group on ID  then  Suppress Group Detail and Group Footer  Problem Solve  Have Fun with Coding